Content Type, existing document type
I am creating a new content type to add a document template. However, I don't want to upload a new document template; instead, I want to use one of the existing documents in our SharePoint environment.
I can add the URL with no issue, but nothing happens when I go back to the document library and click on the template. My word document name is Test template.dotx


